Why is VBA not saving using correct file type when I use a . in the file name?
I have a button in a spreadsheet that automatically saves a file as with the current date-time.
This is my code that doesn't work:
Sub save_update()

Dim path As String
Dim proj_id As String
Dim proj_title As String
Dim timeperiod As String

path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
proj_id = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("master").Range("A2").Value
proj_title = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("master").Range("A3").Value
timeperiod = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy_mm_dd hh.mm.ss")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=path & "\" & timeperiod & " " & proj_id & " " & proj_title & "Internal Tool", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

End Sub

When I press the button, the file saves, but the file extension is undefined.
Specifically, the problem is using . in timeperiod. Delimiting the time with underscores makes it work properly, but using underscores for time is disgusting and goes against my formatting standards. Also, it gets hard to decipher when also using underscores for delimiting the date.
Below example saves file as properly:
timeperiod = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy_mm_dd hh_mm_ss")
Please let me know what I'm doing wrong and help me use hh.mm.ss.
Thank you.

Try saving with a .xlsm at the end of the file name (BTW I wouldn't call underscores in timestamps in filenames disgusting or hard to decipher - I use them all the time ... but fair enough that you prefer the dots instead)

If you use ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (or Save), Excel will check the file name. If it doesn't contains an extension, Excel will append the default extension for the file type you specify. For xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, this will be .xlsm, for xlOpenXMLWorkbook, it's .xlsx, you name it.
However, if the file name already contains an extension, Excel will leave it as it is (even if it is wrong, you can name an Excel file ".docx"). The only way to tell if there is already an extension in the file name is to check for the presence of a Dot. When you write the date with a "." as separator, Excel (and not only Excel) will see everything after the last "." as extension.
The fix is easy (and already mentioned in the comments): Add the extension to your filename manually. I would suggest to use an intermediate variable:
Dim filename As String
filename = path & "\" & timeperiod & " " & proj_id & " " & proj_title & "Internal Tool" & ".xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

